# Bayesian logistic regression from scratch in Python

Tags: bayesian, python

I am trying to code in Python the predictive distribution of a bayesian logistic regression. From the course of [nando de Freitas](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enando/540-2013/lectures/l11.pdf) we know that this is:
$$
p(Y_{n+1} \mid X_{n+1}, D) = \int P(Y_{n+1} \mid \theta, X_{n+1}) P(\theta \mid D)
$$
Where $D=\{ X_{1:n}, Y_{1:n}\}$. We will compute the conditional probability $P(\theta \mid D)$ by MCMC that is we first have to write the unnormalized pdf
$$
P(\theta \mid D) = \frac{1}{Z} \prod_{i=1}^{n}[\pi_i^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{1-y_i}]e^{(-1/2s)\theta^T \theta}
$$
Where we denote $\pi_i = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x_i \theta}}$. Then by MCMC we can get the samples:
$$
\theta^{(i)} \sim P(\theta \mid Y_{1:n} , X_{1:n})
$$
Next we can approimate the predictive distribution with:
$$
p(Y_{n+1} \mid X_{n+1}, D) \approx \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(Y_{n+1} \mid \theta^{(i)}, X_{n+1})
$$
Regarding the Python code I have tried the following I took the following dataset [adult_us_postprocessed.csv](https://github.com/nsanghi/bayesian-methods-for-ml/blob/master/Week%204/Programming%20assignment/adult_us_postprocessed.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


data = pd.read_csv("adult_us_postprocessed.csv")
len(data)
#32561
data.head(20)
```

We have the Metropolis hasting code:

```
eps = 1e-12
 
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
 
def log(x):
    x = x.copy()
    x[x <= eps] = 0
    x[x > 0] = np.log(x[x > 0])  
    return x
 
def log_p_star(data, theta, s=100):
    y = np.array(data['income_more_50K'].tolist())
    p = sigmoid(np.dot(np.hstack((np.ones((len(data), 1)), 
                 data[['age', 'educ']].to_numpy())), theta))
    return np.sum(y*log(p)+(1-y)*log(1-p)) \
           - np.dot(theta.T, theta)/2/s**2 - 3*np.log(s)
 
def mh(param_init, num_samples=5000, stepsize=1.0):
    ## Random-Walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm
    
    ## step 1, initialize
    theta = param_init
    samples = np.zeros((num_samples+1, param_init.shape[0]))
    samples[0] = theta
    
    ## Step 2, iterate
    for i in range(num_samples):
        ## step 2a
        theta_cand = multivariate_normal(mean=theta,cov=[stepsize**2]*len(theta)).rvs(size=1)
        
        ## step 2b
        ll_cand = log_p_star(data = data,theta=theta_cand)
        ll_old = log_p_star(data = data , theta=theta)
        
        ## step 2c
        if ll_cand > ll_old:
            theta = theta_cand
        else:
            u = np.random.uniform()
            if u < np.exp(ll_cand - ll_old):
                theta = theta_cand
                
        ## collect results
        samples[i+1] = theta
     
    return samples
```

We sample 5000 observations:

```
log_p = mh(param_init=np.zeros(3), num_samples=5000)
```

Finally to compute the predictive probability I am not so sure of what I am doing. I have modified the sigmoid to avoid overflow and I have modified the likelihood to be for only one sample and I have added 0.0000001 to avoid overflow again.

```
def sigmoid_pred(x):
    if x < 0:
        return np.exp(x)/(1+np.exp(x))
    else:
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
 
def p_new(x, y, theta, s=100):
    
    p = sigmoid_pred(np.dot(np.insert(x.values, 0, 1, axis=0), theta))
    return y*np.log(p+0.0000001)+(1-y)*np.log(1-p+0.0000001)
# The last observation will be our test set
temp = data[['age', 'educ']]
x = temp.iloc[-1]

temp = data[['income_more_50K']]
y = temp.iloc[-1]
```

The last observation will be our couple $(X_{n+1}, Y_{n+1})$. And finally I think I have to do the following I loop over the last 2000 iterations of the $\theta$ and I evaluate the likelihood for this test data point for $y=0$ and for $y=1$

```
score_list = list()

for i in range(3000,5000):
    score_list.append(p_new(x, 0, theta=log_p[i]))
    
np.mean(score_list)
>>> 9.999e-0.8

score_list = list()

for i in range(3000,5000):
    score_list.append(p_new(x, 1, theta=log_p[i]))
    
np.mean(score_list)
>>> -16.11
```

When I look at the histogram of Nando's course I think I am wrong, it is not the same data but I do not return probabilities and it is predicting that the class of the observation is 0 rather than 1 its true class.
[image]

Comment: I think you have a bug in `log(x)` function, precisely `x[x < eps] = 0` should be replaced with `x[x<eps] = np.log(eps)` or something like that